# How to Integrate rivers with forest in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox

I have 2 type of inputs, Rivers and Forest. Rivers must not move at all (just freeze), only forest should be forced to attach to rivers within a tolerance of 10-20m.

I want to integrate those layer so they perfectly feat each-other, but when i use the integrate tool in arcgis within a xy tolerance, my rivers moves too in some cases.

[image]

Comment: I want to create Integrated lines with same diameter to a line. its better i want to merge or dissolve or unsplit pipelines with the same diameter; but not use editor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SNAP](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Snap/001v00000007000000/) tool. To run this determine a proper distance between forest and river.Now set input layer as "Forest" and snap environment as "Rivers" then select "EDGE" with that proper distance.Run the tool. To get desired result modify the parameters and consult the documentation.

Comment: Yes, but they don't fit perfectly because this procedures doesnt add new vertex if needed, it just snaps existing ones and this leads to non perfectly snaps between features :(

Comment: To add vertex use Densify tool then run snap tool. You have to be very much judicious in case of using snap tool i mean in setting snap environment. You can use Integrate tool when you know that it will not displace the river that much

Comment: If i use as input the rivers, it changes the rivers, i want the rivers to be freeze and only the forest polygon to be moved. I swapped this layer, but in fact if you move lines to polygon you get better results, but this is not my case cause i want polygon to fit lines

Comment: Have you tried Densifying "Forest" and running SNAP as before?

Comment: Yes i densified both of them with a distance of  every 30m, but not the desired results :( . On the other side i already did a generalized so actually it is not ok if i densify it too much because the generalize process i did before doesn't make sense anymore. Actually the best result i can get is from manually use the Map topology with align edge tool, that really does the job, but i dont get it why there isn't anything automatic to do the same?

Comment: Of course topology tool helps. Why densify both layers? I would Densify only "Forest". If you go for manual editing then Align Shape can be another tool for large polygon matching.

Comment: I densify both so they could have same coincident vertex because it doesn't add needed vertex  to fit perfectly, so i tried to make both layer to have needed vertex, but didn't work either. Yes, actually i already used even the Align to shape tool, does the job. But still you have to go manually :(

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the arcgis help page for the integrate tool, it specifies this:

This tool performs the same kind of work as a topology in that it moves features within an x,y tolerance and inserts vertices where features intersect.

Consider using a topology to perform this sort of operation because a topology allows you to specify rules and conditions about how features relate to each other.

For more information about using topologies, see Topology_basics.
You would use Integrate rather than a topology when:

- You do not need to specify any rules about how features are moved—you simply want all features to coalesce within a specified tolerance.
- You want lines to have vertices wherever they intersect.
- You are working with non-geodatabase features such as shapefiles, or with features from different geodatabases (features in a topology must all come from the same feature dataset).

I think the solution is to set up topology on your data.

Comment: The perfect solution is SNAP with the capabilities to add vertex as needed along the snap to the line layer.